# How can I get email notifications when add or remove a tag to a github.com issue?

Tags: github, github-issues

How can I get email notifications when adding or removing a tag to a github.com issue? I need that because we are using tag addition and removal to sign issues status changes. The statuses are specifics to our developemnt process.